# Custom Annotation for ElementType Parameter

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

I have a use case where I need to check if the object is not null, then only execute the method otherwise return.

My current code looks something like this

```
public void someFunction(Object object){
   if(object==null)
      return;
   //some logic
}
```

I want to make a custom annotation which can be applied on parameter of method which can generate this boiler plate. So the new code looks something like this :

```
public void someFunction(@MyAnnotation Object object){
  //some logic
}
```

I have tried Lombok @NonNull, it does the same thing but throws a null pointer exception if the parameter is null. I don't want to throw a exception instead just return from the method.

I want to know how this can be achieved ? Is it possible to do via custom annotation ?